# Login for java not authenticating access for mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I've set up a gui that has a login interface and a database which stores usersnames and passwords, but when im trying to login on the gui its giving me invalid login even when i put in the exact data from my database.

Comment: please check manually mysql username/password.

Comment: I mean to check mysql username/password is correct ?

Comment: `resultset` return some data or empty data ?

Comment: @HarmeetSingh I'm not sure how do you tell?

Comment: if `resultset` return username/password, check the letters cases, because `equals("string")` is case sensitive function.

Comment: What 'is giving you invalid credentials'. Your own code, or a database exception?

Answer (score 1):

Change your Sql Statement as

```
select userName,password from person where userName = ? and password = ?
```

instead of

```
   select userName from person where userName = ? and password = ?
```

**UPDATE**

Infact you no need to check again username and password in java code, your query itself will tells you he/she is valid or not